# Delphi JSON Encode com TSslHttpCli (Overbyte ICS)

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3, httpclient

estou usando o componente TSslHttpCli da Overbyte [www.overbyte.eu](http://www.overbyte.eu/) e estou tendo problemas com a formatação do meu json de retorno, com caracteres especiais, estou consumindo a api geolocation do google, veja o retorno:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"SÃ£o Paulo",
               "short_name":"SÃ£o Paulo",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"SÃ£o Paulo",
               "short_name":"SÃ£o Paulo",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"State of SÃ£o Paulo",
               "short_name":"SP",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brazil",
               "short_name":"BR",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"SÃ£o Paulo, State of SÃ£o Paulo, Brazil",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":-23.3566039,
                  "lng":-46.3650844
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":-24.0082209,
                  "lng":-46.825514
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":-23.5505199,
               "lng":-46.63330939999999
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":-23.3566039,
                  "lng":-46.3650844
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":-24.0082209,
                  "lng":-46.825514
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"ChIJ0WGkg4FEzpQRrlsz_whLqZs",
         "types":[
            "locality",
            "political"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

por exemplo a palavra "SÃ£o Paulo", já alterei o encoding,
já alterei algumas configurações como "Accept", "AcceptLanguage", "Agent", "ContentType", "ContentEncoding" e nad, alguém sabe como resolver? abaixo meu código do HttpCli..

```
HttpCli.Connection      := 'Keep-Alive';
HttpCli.RequestVer      := '1.0';
HttpCli.RcvdStream      := TMemoryStream.Create;;
HttpCli.URL := 'url api...';
HttpCli.Get;

if HttpCli.StatusCode <> 200 then
  begin
   HttpCli.RcvdStream.Free;
   HttpCli.RcvdStream := nil;
   Result := '';
   Exit;
  end;

HttpCli.RcvdStream.Seek(0, 0);
SetLength(Data, HttpCli.RcvdStream.Size);
HttpCli.RcvdStream.Read(Data[1], Length(Data));
xHtmlTemp := String(Data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não é configuração e propriedades do componente, basta trocar

```
xHtmlTemp := String(Data);
```

por

```
xHtmlTemp := UTF8Decode(Data);
```

Estranhei porque no outro componente que usava não precisava desta conversão.